# Shell script if statement always executes else block

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I have written a simple `if`-`else` statement and am calling it from cronjob.

**cronscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Author : TEST USER
# Script follows here:
VAR1="-h"
VAR2="-h"
if [[ "$VAR1" == "$VAR2" ]]; then
    echo "Strings are equal."
else
    echo "Strings are not equal."
fi
```

I'm always getting output as
`Strings are not equal.` Even though both strings are same why it is executing ELSE block?

**cronjob command**

```
34 18 05 * * /var/www/html/cronscript.sh > /var/www/html/testcron.txt
```

cronjob is executing properly and output is stored in testcron.txt file.

Comment: Are you using `dash` as /bin/sh?

Comment: If you paste your script into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) you will get the warning **SC3010 (warning): In POSIX sh, [[ ]] is undefined.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script has the shebang `#!/bin/sh` and tries to use `[[`, which is bash-specific syntax. You should either change the shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Or use plain POSIX sh conditional syntax:

```
if [ "$VAR1" = "$VAR2" ]; then
```